# Frontend is not showing in magento 1.9 but there is no error showing

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

There are some problem with frontend. Please help. In config.xml I wrote the below code

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <faq>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Faq</module>
                    <frontName>faq</frontName>
                </args>
            </faq>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <faq>
                    <file>faq.xml</file>
                </faq>
            </updates>
        </layout> 
    </frontend>
```

Layout: faq.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.4">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/jquery-1.11.1.js</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/accordion.js</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/bootstrap.js</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap.css</name><params/></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <faq_index_index>       
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="faq/faq" name="faq" as="faq" template="faq/faq.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </faq_index_index>
</layout>
```

when I hit the url, blank page is showing like below

[image]

Comment: What is there in that page  phtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="faq/faq" name="faq" as="faq" template="faq/faq.phtml" />
</reference>
```

With this XML, you are saying that this page should use the `faq/faq.phtml` file. What content do you have in that .phtml (`faq/faq.phtml`) file?

**Updated Answer**

Have you created the block file? If it is already created share the code inside the block file.

Also, share the path where your faq.phtml file is located.

Comment: I have faq.phtml page with this tag

<h1>FAQ</h1>

Comment: @sdeveloper I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found ...Where the problem was ..now it is work proper

There is a space in block file name
app\code\local\Citytech\Faq\Block\Fa q.php

Thanks..N. Karthic Kannan helping me to find the error

Comment: That's great !! Please accept and upvote !!